# run a php page in java and return again to php

Tags: java, php

I have to run a test.php in .java like we include("newtest.php"); and return that result to PHP.

Is it possible to do like this ?

Anyone suggest me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more exact. You can not run a php script inside java.

Comment: Agree with @devnull. Can you give a bit more background on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is my php code saved as test.php, i want this code to run in java and return a result to php foreach($guids as $guid)
{
$gud = $guid->getAttribute('guid')."</br>";
$h++;
}

Comment: is it possible to achieve using php java bridge

Comment: An easy method would be, write the php file as an api which will return a json result based on the get parameter. Then from java, send a get request to the php script using any networking packages and parse the result.

Comment: its like user presses a button to get the best set of results using math calculations, in php the calculations gets more time, so i prefer to use java as my bridge to calculate and return result to php...